# Upload an uploaded image using PyImgur without saving to a temporary file

Tags: python, flask, imgur

I want to upload to Imgur an image that was uploaded to my Flask app.  Currently, I save the uploaded file to a temporary file then pass the filename to `upload_image`.  Is there a simpler way that avoids the temporary file?

```
def upload_image():
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    target_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    file.save(target_path)
    im = pyimgur.Imgur(IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
    uploaded_image = im.upload_image(target_path, title=filename)
    os.remove(target_path)
    return uploaded_image.link
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyImgur [only supports passing a filename](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/blob/v0.5.2/pyimgur/__init__.py#L1095) to `upload_image`.  If it supported passing a file object, you could pass the uploaded file directly to it.

You can use the PyImgur client but build the request yourself.  Just do what `upload_image` does internally except use the uploaded file directly.

```
from base64 import b64encode

data = b64encode(request.files['file'].read())
client = pyimgur.Imgur(IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
r = client._send_request('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', method='POST', params={'image': data})
return r['link']
```